# Run windows GUI application in synchronized mode?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, debugging, user-interface

I am debugging GUI app on windows and I want to find out who is the sender of some message. On linux, I can run app in [synchronized mode](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/XSynchronize.html) and find the sender in call stack. Is there any equivalent mode in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no built-in ability to do this.

But let's first investigate the problem. You want to know who's the *sender of the message*. You should know however that windows message processing can be classified by the following criterias:

1. Posted vs Sent messages (`PostMessage` vs `SendMessage`).
2. Messages sent to the window belonging to another thread vs sender thread.
3. Messages posted to a thread (not bound to a specific window, hence not processed by the window procedure).

You may trace directly the sender only when the message is **sent** (not posted) to a window, whereas the call to the `SendMessage` (or similar) was issued in the thread to which the window belongs. In such you will see the sender in the call stack.

In case the message was sent from another thread - you will **not** see it in the call stack. Simply because the call stack shows the call chain that belongs to the current thread only. When a message is sent from another thread the system performs the following:

1. Suspends the caller thread.
2. Puts this message to the queue of the thread that owns the window.
3. When that thread calls `GetMessage` (or similar) - the message is dispatched to the window.
4. Finally the OS resumes the caller thread. The `SendMessage` returns with the result that was returned by the window procedure.

In such a case you may try to identify the caller indirectly. Interrupt your program with the breakpoint, and try to search for suspended threads, which are blocked in a call to `SendMessage` or similar.

Finally, messages that are posted are impossible to trace by the above method. You may try to put a conditional breakpoint on a call to `PostMessage`, but if the caller belongs to another problem - this will be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

valdo is correct. Calls to SendMessage call your applications wndproc directly. Calls to PostMessage posts the message to the message que and your application then recives the message via the message pump (the loop, getmessage, translatemessage, dispatchmessage). So , like he said, if the messages were sent via a SendMessage then the callee of the function will show in the call stack. If it was sent via PostMessage , it will not.

Comment: So there is no way to make PostMessage behave like SendMessage? If so, the only way I see is temporarily replace all PostMessage calls with SendMessage.

Comment: No, there's no way to make Postmessage act like sendmessage, post message is asynchronous, and sends the message to the message que, and as i said send message directly bypasses the message que and calles the applications wndproc directly. When you call PostMessage it returns immediately, but sendmessage blocks on the calling thread, as it accesses the wndproc by calling the wndproc for the hwnd you passed to it.

Comment: This answer is true for single-threaded cases. `SendMessage` works differently across threads, as you must call the WindowProc of a window on its thread, not yours. Since each thread has its own callstack, your SendMessage call won't be on the same stack as the WndProc call.